# Create dropdown with buttons in every option, using angular 6 +

Tags: angular, button, angular6, dropdown, ngfor

I have a dropdown in angular 6 that I create using `ngFor`. Now, in every option, I would like to add a functional `button`.

The obvious solution would be

```
<select formControlName="van">           
  <option *ngFor='let item of vanArray' value="{{item.id}}" > {{item.name}}  
     <button type="button" (click)="whatever(item.id)" name="button">delete</button> 
  </option>
</select>
```

This kinda works. I get no errors whatsoever, but the button is never rendered as a button, I get just a "delete " text , next to each option, that is not clickable.

How can I do this?

Thanks

PS : is it possible to use just angular and not any package?

Comment: I'm not sure what just angular means, but I may suggest to use bootstrap.css + angular see button group https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/button-group/#nesting or the ngbootstrap drop-down https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples